# Multiple Files in FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing, nameerror

I need to upload multiple image files via FastApi. I am using this code:

```
@app.post("/analyze")
async def analyze(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
for img in files:
    contents = await img.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(contents, np.uint8)
    img1 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    print(img1.shape)
    img1 = resize_image(img1)
    print(img1.shape)
```

But it is showing error as:

```
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

Please help!

I would try to upload multiple images via fastapi and then perform opencv operations on it. Also where to upload image if I am using Postman instead for SwaggerUI for testing?

Comment: `List` lives in `typing`: `from typing import List`

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you tell where to upload image if I am using Postman instead of Swagger UI? I am currently using form data to upload image but it is returning 'method not allowed.

Comment: That would probably be a Postman specific question if it works otherwise. Postman would need to use a `multipart/form-data` encoding for the post data; not sure how you do that in postman.

Answer (score 1):

Import this

```
from typing import List
```